# Apply css value for each iteration ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I try to apply a `css` value (itemPosition) for each iteration of my `ng-repeat`. I call a function that returns me a value (0 to 100). I applied to the `css` property `left`.

For example, I have the following values: 
53.345, 64.982 or 84.234

All `left css` properties are set to: 84.234. 
While I would have:

> iteration 1, `left: 53345`; 
>    iteration 2, `left: 64982`; 
>    iteration 3, `left: 84234`;

My view :

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="setItemPosition(item.x)" >
      <div class="circle" style="position: relative; left: {{itemPosition}}%;" >
           <div class="circle-text">{{item.value}}</div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

In my controller, i have this function (The function returns a percentage) :

```
 $scope.setItemPosition = function(value) {
    var diffDate = ($scope.intervalResearchTime.endDateTime - $scope.intervalResearchTime.startDateTime) / 100;
    var valueToPercent = ((value - $scope.intervalResearchTime.startDateTime) / diffDate);
    $scope.itemPosition = valueToPercent; //exemple = 84.234;
};
```

It's possible to do something ?

Comment: Use the tag `ng-style` instead of `style` to execute Angular Expressions within your in-line style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ng-style` with `function`

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div class="circle" ng-style="getStyle(item.x)">
       <div class="circle-text">{{item.value}}</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.getStyle = function(value) {
    var diffDate = ($scope.intervalResearchTime.endDateTime - $scope.intervalResearchTime.startDateTime) / 100;
    var valueToPercent = ((value - $scope.intervalResearchTime.startDateTime) / diffDate);
    return { left: valueToPercent + 'px' } ;
};
```

**CSS**

```
 .circle {
    position: relative;
 }
```

Check out jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fizerkhan/eXL28/3/

Comment: Now all my values ​​are located at 0 percent. why ? Do you have an idea?

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand.

Comment: When i do, <div class="circle" ng-style="getStyle(item.x)"> it doesn't work. It is all the time at position 0%, as if the css style does not apply. However, if I set in my html page <div class="circle" style="left: 80%;"> : It Works!. Why? Do you have an idea?

Comment: Did you check the return values of `getStyle()`? Debug or put `console.log` before returning result. I have added semicolons at the end in the return style.

Comment: Yes, and it's look like good. 
`var testReturnData = 'left: ' + valueToPercent + '%;';`
`$log.log('ValueToPercent : ' + testReturnData); result` --> `ValueToPercent : left: 83.2480011574074%;`

Comment: I made a mistake, the return result of ng-style function should be object, NOT a string. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can render `data-attr` in the html and set a css property: `left: attr(name_of_attribute);`

I.e:

```
<div class='circle' data-position='{{itemPosition}}%'></div>


.circle {
  left: attr(data-position);
}
```